# Reactjs: onClick from componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
clickMenu(){
    this.props.handler('900')
}

componentWillMount(){
    var list = "";

    function setMenu(value){
        value.map(value => {
            list += '<div class="parentMenu"><span onClick={clickMenu}>'+value.title+'</span>'
            if(value.child){
                list += '<div class="subMenu">'
                setMenu(value.child)
                list += '</div>'
            }
            list += '</div>'
        })
    }

    setMenu(Tools.menuArray)
}

...

return ...
<nav dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.menu}}></nav>
```

I create menu with submenus dynamically

I want if I click on `span`, `clickMenu` run and pass this data to `clickMenu` function

how I can use onClick and function into append variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here, what `setMenu` is, or why you're doing it here instead of just doing it in the render or normal helper function.

Comment: with `setMenu` I create tree menu. @DaveNewton